# Pass parameter from Jquery to c#

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

i am developeing site with possibilty for users to send messages one to another.
As i see the solution of these problem is:

- Read the message data from code behind (c#) and pass data of message to aspx which should display relevant information within jquery script routine.
- When user reads specific message i though about to update the message status in DB that this specific message has been red. At this point i was wondering if this good idea to pass some parameter from jquery to c# in order to update DB.

Is this good solution at your opinion ? May be its good idea to use AJAX ?
If you can provide some small example, it would be highly appritiated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you render your aspx with the message you already know the message will be read by the user, so you can update the db there.

If you need to do it from the browser using jquery anyway (maybe because of another condition I'm not aware of) you could try WebMethods. This link seems pretty useful: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Hope it helps.